# how to read data from textfile in java with conditions that data has to be read from one position to another position

Tags: java, buffer, text-files

I want to read text file from event 1 to end 1 first and then event 2 to end 2 and so on , there will be multiple lines in code that are between one event to another event.
The text file is like following :

```
event 1 arg  arg  arg  end 1 
event 2 arg arg arg end 2
```

Comment: So where is your problem with what you've tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, try that

```
public void method() {
    String file = "C:\\text.txt";
    LineNumberReader reader = null;
    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;
    String line=null;
    int i;
    try {
        reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(file));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            i = reader.getLineNumber();
            String template = "event" + i + ".+end" + i;
            pattern = Pattern.compile(template);
            matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(line.substring((matcher.start()), matcher.end()));
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

In file is

```
event1 arg arg arg end1
event2 arg arg arg end2
```

And output the same